# Pass an operator without backticks

Tags: r

I have a function that I want to pass an operator to, like so:

```r
foo <- function(a, b, op){
  op(a, b)
}

foo(1, 2, `>`)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is exactly what I want. My question is, can I achieve the same goal *without* the backticks? That is, so the function call would be

```r
foo(1, 2, >)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible just because the parser isn't going to see an operator as the name of a function, but rather as a request to do a particular operation.  It's possible to use quotes instead of backticks for binary operators (but not unitary) like this ```foo <- function(a, b, op){
  op <- match.fun(FUN = op)
  op(a, b)
}
foo(1, 2, ">")``` but I doubt that really helps you...

Comment: Why the aversion to backticks?

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your thoughts. I thought as much, but wondered if there was an `enquo`, `!!`, etc. type workaround. @Downvoter If you could explain how I could improve my question, I'd appreciate the input. @r2evans It's not an aversion, as such, I was just curious if there was a way in an effort to improve understanding of the nuts-and-bolts of R.

Comment: It's a good exercise, and I think it demonstrates a good distinction between R's parsing of expressions (before the function *fires*) and non-standard evaluation within the function. (Yeah, down-votes can be frustrating ... sometimes I think it's more about "swipe-left"/uninterested and less about "poorly asked or inappropriate". I'm learning to brush these off more, it's an uphill battle for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this does not fully answer your question, but you can use `magrittr` to avoid backsticks:

```
foo(a = 1, b = 2, op = is_less_than)

[1] TRUE

foo(a = 1, b = 2, op = is_greater_than)

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Expanding this a bit (although I agree it likely doesn't fully answer the question).  One can put any operator into a dummy function like ```is_less_than``` by doing this ```bar <- `>` ```.  Then it's possible to call ```foo(1, 2, bar)```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of the long way around, but if you have a strictly limited set of operators you intend to use, you could create a bunch of functions.  (this is an extension of the idea in tmfmnk's answer)

```
myplus <-function(x,y) x + y
mygt <- function(x,y) x > y
```

and so on. This requires more keystrokes than simply typing

```
`>`
```

But at least it avoids having to think about backticks.

Even worse :-),  create a vector of char arrays

```
myops = c('>','<' , '%%',[etc])
```

and pass `myops[k]` as an argument to the function, either parsing it internally or setting up a `switch` construction which applies the desired operator based on the char string you supply.  I don't recommend this except as an exercise in learning how `R` works with parsing, expressions, etc.